# Java - Converting ASCII to Binary without leading zeros

Tags: java, binary, byte, ascii

I am using this code:

```
    byte[] bytes = MESSAGE.getBytes();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b : bytes) {
        int val = b;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            str.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
        }
    }
```

and I'm trying to modify it to remove leading zerosfrom the binary code of every ASCII character before it gets appended to binary `StringBuilder str`. But the problem is the number of leading zeros is unknown and I can only remove them from the entire binary block by adding the following after the first block:

```
    String MSG = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if(str.charAt(i) == '0')
            MSG = (str.toString()).substring(i+1,str.length());
        else
            break;
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: She doesn't want the leading zeroes, because now she has to remove them when she uses her string printing method.

Comment: @brso05 I'm trying to remove the leading zeros of every character before appending their binaries together here: `str.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer.toBinaryString(yourByte).replaceFirst("0*", "");

A more complete example would be.

```
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String example = "A test string";

for( byte b: example.getBytes()){
    builder.append(Integer.toBinaryString(b).replaceFirst("0*",""));
}   

System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Comment: She only wants to remove leading zeroes until a 1 is found. Leading zeroes of bytes after that are not to be removed because they have a leading 1 from a previous byte.

Comment: I don't know what you  are saying. You can give it a shot. http://ideone.com/AVZc4r

Comment: "001001" should be converted to "1100000011000000110001001100000011000000110001", which is the binary representation of the ASCII codes of that string (0 is 00110000 and 1 is 00110001). Your code converts it to "1001"

Comment: My code is only to convert a byte, and I provided an example of the byte conversion. Not taking "001001" as a string but showing that any byte string will have only the leading zeros removed. eg. The code I pasted above will turn a byte into a string of 0's and 1's then remove the leading zeros.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
byte[] bytes = MESSAGE.getBytes();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (byte b : bytes) {
    int val = b;
    boolean dontWriteYet = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int digit = (val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        if(digit == 1 && dontWriteYet ) {
            dontWriteYet = false;
        } 
        if (!dontWriteYet) {
            str.append(digit);
        }
        val <<= 1;
    }
    //if all 0's then we must add the 0
    if (dontWriteYet){
        str.append(0);
    }
}
```

Basically do not write to str until you get a 1.  Once you get a 1, then write the rest.

EDITTED code to add case where all 0's.

Comment: ah yes, looks like we had the same idea, but executed it slightly different.

Answer (score 2):

It does look complicated, because you use the ternary operator, but it is actually not that hard to modify the code to omit leading zeroes:

```
byte[] bytes = MESSAGE.getBytes();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
boolean first = true;
for (byte b : bytes) {
    int val = b;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        int v = (val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        if (v == 1 || !first || i == 7) {
            str.append(v);
            first = false;
        }
        val <<= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: great minds think alike.  though matt's solution is pretty slick.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to use a flag to mark when you find a 1 and only add characters when such flag is true. That solution has one inconvenient, you have to check that flag EACH time. A more efficient solution would be to have different code for traversing zeroes and for adding characters :

```
static class Indexes {

    int indexByte;
    int indexBit;
}

static void traverseZeroes(byte[] bytes, Indexes indexes) {
    for (indexes.indexByte = 0; indexes.indexByte < bytes.length; ++indexes.indexByte) {
        int val = bytes[indexes.indexByte];
        for (indexes.indexBit = 0; indexes.indexBit < 8; ++indexes.indexBit) {
            if ((val & 128) != 0) {
                return;
            }
            val <<= 1;
        }
    }
}

static void addBits(byte[] bytes, Indexes indexes, StringBuilder str) {
    if ( indexes.indexByte>=bytes.length ) {
        str.append('0');
        return;
    }
    int val = bytes[indexes.indexByte] << indexes.indexBit;
    for (;;) {
        while (indexes.indexBit < 8) {
            str.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
            val <<= 1;
            ++indexes.indexBit;
        }
        indexes.indexBit = 0;
        ++indexes.indexByte;
        if (indexes.indexByte >= bytes.length) {
            break;
        }
        val = bytes[indexes.indexByte];
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] bytes = MESSAGE.getBytes();
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    Indexes indexes = new Indexes();
    traverseZeroes(bytes, indexes);
    addBits(bytes, indexes, str);
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

In the unlikely case that perfomance is important enough use that. Otherwise use the flag.

Comment: You only have to check the flag on 0s, so before you find the first 1 this idea is roughly the same and then it gets better. Also I think it's better to use 0 or '0' so no object gets created. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: True, I've changed "0" to '0'.

Answer (score 0):

Could you start with the ASCII code as an `Integer` and then call `.toBinaryString()` on that? I think that would get rid of the zeros. [Docs are here if it helps.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString(int))

To get an `Integer` value you can just cast directly from the character.

```
public String characterToBinary(char c){
    int ascii = (int) c;
    return Integer.toBinaryString(ascii);
}
```

If it's an `Integer` you also have access to other useful methods like `.numberOfLeadingZeros()`.